# Folders visible when opening jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I open Jupyter Notebooks, I see all of the folders under "Owner" on my computer (including My Documents, My Pictures, etc). I wanted to see if there was any way that I could install Anaconda or use Jupyter notebooks so that these folders are not seen. Having all of those folders clutters the screen, I just want folders for my datasets and notebooks.

In addition, when I open it in localhost and I see these folders (My Documents, My Pictures).

Does this mean that these files are copied onto python's servers?  Or would it only be accessible from my computer?

Comment: just cd to your working dir before running `jupyter notebook`

Comment: or `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir="directory"`

Comment: How would I do this?  Do I do this in the command prompt or in the browser window.

Comment: You can also shift + right click on the directory where you want to open up a Juptyer Notebook and select 'Open Command Prompt Here' (or Windows PowerShell or git bash if you prefer).

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default directory of Jupyter Notebook.

1. Go to `.jupyter` folder. It's usually in `<USER NAME>/.jupyter`
2. Open the config file `jupyter_notebook_config.py` in a text editor
3. If the file was missing, create it first by running the command:
   `jupyter notebook --generate-config`
4. Change it at:
   `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'D:/'`

Comment: I can't find a config file with that name.  When I open the .jupyter folder there is just a migration file.

Comment: Which Versions of Python/Notebook are you using?

Comment: Anyway, you can generate this file with a command:   jupyter notebook --generate-config

Comment: I am using Python 3.  I've been able to do a config file, but I tried making the D:/ drive my directory as well as various folders on C:/.  However, I still see every folder I have on my computer.

Comment: You have to shutdown and start Jupyter Notebook after changing the config file

Answer (score 2):

If someone is a complete newbie to using Jupyter Notebook, like me, then here's the elaboration to Yasin Yousif and ALollz comments:

1. Open Jupyter Notebook which results in the Juyter Dashboard.
2. Open new terminal from here.

[image]

3. This is where the solutions suggested by Yasin Yousif and ALollz need to be implemented:

[image]